# I'm trying to dual boot ubuntu 22.04 and win10 but it always boot up win10. If i press f9, i get to choose ubuntu so far nothing have worked for me

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, windows-10, bootloader

Win10 is preinstalled
The system is Hp 650
I've selected dev/sda, dev/sda(the partition number), windows Boot manager as the device for the bootloader installation it still boots to win10 without asking to choose. However if I press f9 I can choose between ubuntu and win10

Answer (score 2):

HP - <kbd>escape</kbd>  + <kbd>F9</kbd> for UEFI boot menu, <kbd>F10</kbd> for UEFI/bios settings

HP seems to be the only vendor that does not support boot order change with efibootmgr which grub uses to change order. Applies to most models.

Use <kbd>F10</kbd> for UEFI settings and change boot order there. Then boot menu should show Ubuntu as first.
It may be sub-menu & be sure to save settings changes so it applies.

Grub will boot working Windows.

Windows updates may turn fast start up/hibernation back on and then you need to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu to turn it back off for grub to work again to boot Windows.

hp 250 g3  Change boot order in UEFI settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467077

Comment: @oldfredthe boot menu doesn't show ubuntu

Comment: Not boot menu, but UEFI settings menu for boot devices. And it probably is a sub-menu. If still not shown, did you install in UEFI boot mode? To see details Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/